# How to set an specific value in mongoose Schema id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose-schema

I need to pass a specific value to the id propertie of the mongoose Schema so i can relate collections.

I've tried passing the _id: false so mongoose wouldn't create the id field automaticaly with some random value.

I wrote this schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const DetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  value: Number
}, {_id: false});

const Details = mongoose.model('details', DetailsSchema);

module.exports = Details;
```

This is my route to receive the specific value:

```
router.post('/api/newSolicitation', async (req, res) => {
const { value, id, name } = req.body;
const checkforid = await Details.findOne({id});

if(checkforid) {
  const result = await Details.save();
  console.log('Detail updated: ', result);

  res.json({
    success: true,
    message: 'Detail Updated'
  });
}
else {
    const detail = new Details({
        id,
        name,
        value
    });

    const submit = await detail.save();
    console.log('New detail created:', submit);

    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'New detail created!'
    });
   }  
});
```

I have this error message:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving
```

Which i don't understand because i already declared the _id and it's value.

Comment: You also say you need to relate collections. In this case, manually doing IDs may be totally unnecessary and you might have much easier way to do this. E.g. if you have a `detail._id` and you save it to some other collection as `thing.detailId = detail._id`, you can still connect those two collections. But that depends on your use case. What is it exactly that you wanna do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to search and create by `id` instead of `_id`.

You **have** to provide `_id` to a document or let MongoDB generate one for you.

Remove `{ _id: false }`  and provide `_id` on insert, Its impossible to create a document without `_id` because `_id` is required for replication.

```
router.post('/api/newSolicitation', async (req, res) => {
  // destucture id from req.body and rename it to _id 
  // { property: newPropertyName }
  const { id: _id, name, value } = req.body;
  const checkforid = await Details.findById(_id);

  if(checkforid) {
    const result = await Details.save();
    console.log('Detail updated: ', result);

    return res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Detail Updated'
    });
  }
  const detail = new Details({ _id, name, value }).save();
  console.log('New detail created:', detail);

  res.json({
    success: true,
    message: 'New detail created!'
  });
});
```

Comment: The id you are refering is the id value i want to pass to the database. I just searched for that value to make sure it doesn't exist. If it exists i just update it, if it doesn't i pass the value on to creation.....or I'm misunderstanding something. I've already tested it letting mongo create _id while I create a new field called id and i still get the same error tho.

Comment: Remove `{_id: false}` from the schema and try to insert a new Detail like this `const detail = await new Details({_id: id, name,  value}).save();` `console.log(detail);` and tell me if the error still exist